# Eigen:Avoid using for loop

Tags: optimization, openmp, eigen

In the below code instead of using for loop I wanted to implement a one line code that would use  Eigen library functions and help in vectorisation of code itself and thus making parallelization through OpenMP easy.

```
Eigen::VectorXd get_vector(int n, int j , int start){
    Eigen::VectorXd foo(n);
    indices = Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(n, start + n - 1, start).array();

    for(int i =0;i<indices.size();i++)
        foo(i) = (array(indices(i)) - array(j))*(array(indices(i)) - array(j));

return foo;

}
// array is globally declared as Eigen::VectorXd and have length greater than n, it is already been defined.(set of N(>n) random double numbers)
```

Comment: Do you mean `foo(i)=...`? And what is `array`?

Comment: @chtz           Yes, I edited the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `array` is an `VectorXd` and you don't need `indices` outside your function:

```
return (array.segment(start, n).array() - array(j)).square();
```

And you should consider returning a `ArrayXd` instead of `VectorXd`.
If `array` is actually a `ArrayXd`, you can omit the `.array()`.

Comment: My array is VectorXd and as I did what u have mentioned, it gave me an error, on further debugging it seems subtraction was giving an error. Any idea why such thing is happening?  Error comes as "::: no match for ‘operator-’"

Comment: header/Eigen/src/Core/../plugins/CommonCwiseUnaryOps.h:45: note: candidates are: const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar>, const Derived> Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::operator-() const [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, 1, 0, -0x00000000000000001, 1>]

Comment: Yes, it worked.But I didn't understand why array() is required? Doesn't Eigen Vector supports scalar subtraction?

Comment: @user7440094 The `Eigen::Vector` and `Eigen::Matrix` are mathematical objects, so if an operation does not make mathematical sense, it is usually not implemented. If you want to treat an `Eigen::Vector` or `Eigen::Matrix` just as a series of its elements, then you must tell Eigen so explicitly via `m.array()`. Thus `a*b != a.array()*b.array()` and subtracting a scalar from a vector must be done as an array (and converted back to a matrix, explicitly or implicitly) as it does not make mathematical sense to subtract a scalar from a vector, nor a vector from a matrix, etc.